# org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `elasticsearch-8.2.2` in my project and I am getting below error when I'm trying to start the `elasticsearch-8.2.2` server. I'm using mac.

Error:

```
[2022-06-13T10:07:35,261][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] parsed [0] roles from file [/Users/prats/Documents/Prateek/elk/elasticsearch-8.2.2/config/roles.yml]

[2022-06-13T10:07:35,879][INFO ][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator   ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb}]
[2022-06-13T10:07:35,893][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
[2022-06-13T10:07:35,908][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2022-06-13T10:07:36,366][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] initialized
[2022-06-13T10:07:36,366][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] starting ...
[2022-06-13T10:07:36,430][INFO ][o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] persistent cache index loaded
[2022-06-13T10:07:36,430][INFO ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] deprecation component started
[2022-06-13T10:07:36,480][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2022-06-13T10:07:36,881][INFO ][o.e.c.c.Coordinator      ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] cluster UUID [BXhbMnOMSHCsi5hQcfT-9w]
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,036][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local}{VZo5UgAYQAiFG0_DBzrLGw}{RE8DYyfpRECSSZaYGjdivg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw} completing election], term: 4, version: 141, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local}{VZo5UgAYQAiFG0_DBzrLGw}{RE8DYyfpRECSSZaYGjdivg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,114][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] master node changed {previous [], current [{Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local}{VZo5UgAYQAiFG0_DBzrLGw}{RE8DYyfpRECSSZaYGjdivg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}, term: 4, version: 141, reason: Publication{term=4, version=141}
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,131][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] publish_address {192.168.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,132][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] started
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,378][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] license [38db70a1-a789-47c7-841e-bea5da026f2a] mode [basic] - valid
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,378][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.Realms         ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] license mode is [basic], currently licensed security realms are [reserved/reserved,file/default_file,native/default_native]
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,380][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] recovered [12] indices into cluster_state
[2022-06-13T10:07:37,511][ERROR][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] exception during geoip databases update
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of [.geoip_databases] index are active
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:135) ~[ingest-geoip-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:275) [ingest-geoip-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:102) [ingest-geoip-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:48) [ingest-geoip-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:773) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
[2022-06-13T10:07:39,477][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] path: /.kibana_task_manager/_search, params: {ignore_unavailable=true, index=.kibana_task_manager}
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:730) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:417) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:762) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:514) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$1.onFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:348) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$Delegating.onFailure(ActionListener.java:92) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:48) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler.handleException(SearchTransportService.java:642) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$UnregisterChildTransportResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1609) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1346) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1468) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1443) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TaskTransportChannel.sendResponse(TaskTransportChannel.java:50) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ChannelActionListener.onFailure(ChannelActionListener.java:47) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable.onFailure(ActionRunnable.java:77) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.onFailure(ThreadContext.java:761) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:28) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:496) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    ... 16 more
[2022-06-13T10:07:39,496][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] path: /.kibana_task_manager/_search, params: {ignore_unavailable=true, index=.kibana_task_manager}
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:730) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:417) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:762) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:514) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$1.onFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:348) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$Delegating.onFailure(ActionListener.java:92) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:48) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler.handleException(SearchTransportService.java:642) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$UnregisterChildTransportResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1609) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1346) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1468) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1443) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TaskTransportChannel.sendResponse(TaskTransportChannel.java:50) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ChannelActionListener.onFailure(ChannelActionListener.java:47) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable.onFailure(ActionRunnable.java:77) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.onFailure(ThreadContext.java:761) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:28) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:496) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    ... 16 more
[2022-06-13T10:07:39,514][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] path: /.kibana_task_manager/_search, params: {ignore_unavailable=true, index=.kibana_task_manager}
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:730) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:417) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:762) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:514) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$1.onFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:348) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$Delegating.onFailure(ActionListener.java:92) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:48) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler.handleException(SearchTransportService.java:642) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$UnregisterChildTransportResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1609) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1346) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1468) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1443) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TaskTransportChannel.sendResponse(TaskTransportChannel.java:50) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ChannelActionListener.onFailure(ChannelActionListener.java:47) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable.onFailure(ActionRunnable.java:77) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.onFailure(ThreadContext.java:761) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:28) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:496) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    ... 16 more
[2022-06-13T10:07:39,533][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local] path: /.kibana_task_manager/_search, params: {ignore_unavailable=true, index=.kibana_task_manager}
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:730) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:417) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:762) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:514) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$1.onFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:348) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$Delegating.onFailure(ActionListener.java:92) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:48) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler.handleException(SearchTransportService.java:642) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$UnregisterChildTransportResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1609) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1346) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1468) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1443) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TaskTransportChannel.sendResponse(TaskTransportChannel.java:50) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ChannelActionListener.onFailure(ChannelActionListener.java:47) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRunnable.onFailure(ActionRunnable.java:77) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.onFailure(ThreadContext.java:761) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:28) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: [Prateeks-MacBook-Pro.local][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:549) ~[elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onShardFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:496) [elasticsearch-8.2.2.jar:8.2.2]
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: try deleting the `.geoip_database` index, then restarting Elasticsearch

Comment: You can't delete `.geoip_database` yourself but what is able to delete it is ES itself when you set `ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled: false`. Restart ES, it'll delete the index, then set it back to true or remove the line if you want to re-enable it, restart again, and it'll redownload the databases (hopefully, correctly this time, like it did for me).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to disable geoip indexing download by adding `ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled: false` to `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Answer (score 8):

If your testing locally Try to disable the following

```
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: false  <---here

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false <---here



# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false <---here
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: false <---here
```

Comment: Which file you're talking about ?

Comment: it's eleasticsearch.yml file in /config directory @PAA

Comment: this solution worked for me in Windows 11, consuming the API on a jupyter notebook

Answer (score 8):

For those using Docker Compose, add `ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled=false` to the `environment`:

```
environment:
  - ingest.geoip.downloader.enabled=false
```

You can also map a local file to an `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```
volumes:
  - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Source: [GeoIpDownloader can't be disabled by elasticsearch.yml](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/76586#issuecomment-1001719618)